# useParams value is executing useEffect when params constant is indise of array dependecies and I´m resizing app page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

This useEffect is executed every time I resize my page. video is a DB document

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";


 const params = useParams();
    
useEffect(() => {
            if (
              (params.id && !video) ||
              (!!params.id && !!video && params.id !== video?._id)
            ) {
              dispatch(addViewVideo({ _id: params.id }));
              dispatch(getVideo({ _id: params.id }));
            }
          }, [params]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useParams` `params` reference is likely a ***new*** object reference each render cycle. Since `params.id` is the only dependency I see from the `params` object, `params.id` should be the dependency, not the entire `params` object. It also appears that `video` is a missing dependency and should be added.

Example:

```js
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (
    (id && !video) ||
    (!!id && !!video && id !== video?._id)
  ) {
    dispatch(addViewVideo({ _id: id }));
    dispatch(getVideo({ _id: id }));
  }
}, [id, video]);
```